# android Emulator doesn't work (Adb)

Tags: android

I am having an issue with Android Emulator I'm trying to run my app but it doesn't work out I don't know why I've already installed Google USB driver in the SDK manager

[image: this is what is shows up]

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

seems you have problem with Adb
you need to restart your emulator first
if no needed reset you adb in android device monitor